# Only ls operation uses getdents()/getdents64()?

Tags: linux, ls

The operation of ls will call getdents64(),but I do not find other operations call it.Only ls uses getdents()/getdents64()?

Comment: You haven't really asked a question. Can you please rephrase to tell us what you want to know? Are you asking what other commands use `getdents64()`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Just to let you know, this is not the sort of question that goes down well here, if it is a question at all. It's completely unclear what you are asking. I encourage you to browse the site and look at some of the questions with a lot of up-votes to get a sense of what this site is all about. In the meantime, I'm going to recommend that this question be closed, and I invite you to post a new, more detailed question if you want to get any answers.

Answer (score 0):

`getdents(2)` is a system call.  It is called by `readdir(3)` which is quite common.

```
$ strace -e getdents find >/dev/null
getdents(5, /* 26 entries */, 32768)    = 936
getdents(5, /* 0 entries */, 32768)     = 0
+++ exited with 0 +++
```